# What is the purpose of this Unity3D code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am keen to understand a bit more on what's the code given below:

```
rotPlayerAmrs.x -= rotamountY;

rotplayerArms.z = 0;

rotPlayer.y  += rotAmountX;
```

What does this mean? I didn't understand the calculation. And also what is the use for doing this? Where can this be done on? There is an image pinned which shows a detailed code of this:

[image]

Comment: That's not the **depracated** "unityscript" but `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is attempting to

- rotate the player's arms
- rotate the whole player

based on

- what the user does with the mouse

There are so many problems in the code it's hard to know where to begin!  But in answer to your question "what is it doing" - that's the answer.